# SymmetricDS: router to all or specific node

Tags: symmetricds

I have a table with column indicate sync to all or specific node, the data will be "ALL" or "001" for example.

However, one same record could be configured with "ALL" or "001", the record "ALL" could be overwriting my "001" record...

How can I specified in sym router, that I route "ALL" record to the node if none "001" record exist ?

Answer (score 0):

let’s say your table is ‘my_table’ and the routing column is ‘route_to’. set the subselect query column of sym_router to

```
c.external_id in (select distinct sn.external_id
from sym_node sn
where (sn.external_id = :ROUTE_TO or ‘ALL’ = :ROUTE_TO))
```

Comment: But then let say my first record is "ALL", and second record is "001", for node 001 I only need record "001", for other node 002, 003, etc will get record "ALL"

Comment: For my node 001, I will receive both "ALL" and "001" record

Comment: What's the name of your routing column?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169999/discussion-between-csl-and-boris-pavlovic).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this with the following subselect query.

This will check to see if the target node matches the records external_id or if the external_id is 'ALL' it will check to make sure there are no other records in the table with the node's id.

```
c.external_id = :ROUTE_TO 
    OR (:ROUTE_TO = 'ALL' AND c.external_id NOT IN (
            select distinct route_to from my_table where route_to = :ROUTE_TO
        )
    )
```

I still feel like something is missing. Is this some type of parameter table? If so, you would want to modify the inner select to make sure you aren't looking at the full table but only records that match on parameterName.

Comment: Maintenance table. i think what explain in my question is not support by symmetric, because each row is route on its own, but I want to force it to do a full table select before route, which is not right I think...

Comment: The sub select provided will scan the full table to make sure an 'All' record isn't sent if a better match is available for a node.